# Access a background process in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, process, symfony-process

I would like to create a background process in Symfony2, using the [Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) and run it in background, like this:

```
$process = new Process('php myfile.php --option1 --option2');
$process->start();
```

The script which I want to run here would run indefinetely (`while (true)` or something like that) and should be possible to kill from a console command or from a controller.

The question is - how can I access such a process in Symfony (e.g. from a controller) from a different context than it was created? That is - without the original `Process` instance? Let's say a request to a route `create_process` starts the process, then a request to `kill_process` should kill it. Is it even possible?

One way I can think of is serializing the process object and storing in in the database but it seems there could be lots of problems with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this.

PHP is *stateless*, each Request is completely unique.

I don't know how Symfony Processes work internally, but AFAIK there is no way to kill commands executed through `exec()`,`passthru()` or the like.

You could read this section and find out if it helps: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#process-pid

If it doesn't you could still get the current timestamp (e.g. 1422971460) when you start the process, and periodically check for the existence of a file called "kill_1422971460", and as soon as it exists, delete it and end the process.

But I would advise you to use another programming language for this kind of processes, as PHP is not designed for this. Also you can hit `max_execution_time` or timeouts between apache and fcgi threads, which will end up killing your process. It's not reliable and it won't serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this using the DaemonizableCommandBundle:

- https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command

It has a  `EndlessCommand` class that you can extend and create a command that does something in a loop, and which you could terminate anytime; it does try to terminate the iteration gracefully.